# the ref number returned by getrefcount function

Tags: python

below is example:

```
from sys import getrefcount
getrefcount(1) #1
getrefcount(2) #2
getrefcount('a')  #3
a='a'
getrefcount(a)   #4    
getrefcount("aaaaaaaa") #5
a='aaaaaaaa'
getrefcount(a)  #6
```

And the outcoming is:
[image]

I konw it is because the python stores some small object for reuse.But,I want to know how to explain the #4~#6 numbers?why is 2 and 3? Which variable reference it?

Comment: Note that your interpreter session does not match the script above. I get `2` and `2` for #s 5 and 6 (note that calling `sys.getrefcount` will always add one reference).

Comment: I get `3` and `2` for `#5` and `#6`, same as the OP

Comment: I have changed script. why is 3 and 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding number 5 and 6 (return 3 and 2)

According to the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount):

> The count returned is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount().

When passing a value ('aaaaaaaa')  python creates another temporary variable so it's equal to

```
_temp = 'aaaaaaaa'
getrefcount(_temp)
```

Which are 2 references + the temp one used by getrefcount

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Is 2 references mean that variable "a" and one variable which python preset itself?

Comment: 2 means variable a + one used by getrefcount